# Way to access ArrayList from other method in same class without passing argument?

Tags: java, arraylist, scope, arguments

I'm trying to have my method "add" access the contents of an ArrayList that was created in method "Friends", but Java isn't happy with what I'm doing (scope issues?). Is there a way to fix the problem without having to pass arguments?

```
public class Friends {
public Friends(float x, float y)
    {       
        ArrayList<MyObject> arrayList = new ArrayList<MyObject>(); 
        MyObject[] friendList = new MyObject[20];

    }

public void add()
    {       
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            //friendList[i]
        }
    }
}
```

note that Friends is meant to be a constructor (if I'm using that word right)

Comment: friendList should be a instance field instead of a local variable in the constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously for such cases you should use such called "object variables", or simply saying - fields of the class. You should make your variable `arrayList` part of the class as a field:

```
public class Friends {
List<MyObject> arrayList;
public Friends(float x, float y)
    {       
        arrayList = new ArrayList<MyObject>(); 
        MyObject[] friendList = new MyObject[20];

    }

public void add()
    {       
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            //arrayList.add(...).
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your variables *member variables* of the **Friends** class:

```
public class Friends {
ArrayList<MyObject> arrayList;
MyObject[] friendList;
public Friends(float x, float y)
    {       
        arrayList = new ArrayList<MyObject>(); 
        friendList = new MyObject[20];

    }

public void add()
    {       
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            //friendList[i]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is correct. The problem here is scoping. You are creating a local variable `arrayList` in the constructor, which is only available in the constructor.

You should declare it as an instance variable like this:

```
public class Friends {

    ArrayList<MyObject> arrayList; = new ArrayList<MyObject>(); 
    MyObject[] friendList; = new MyObject[20];

    public Friends(float x, float y)
    {       
        this.arrayList = new ArrayList<MyObject>(); 
        this.friendList = new MyObject[20];
    }

public void add()
{       
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        //friendList[i]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "Global" is misleading. It's an instance or member variable.

Comment: You're absolutely right I changed it to instance variable. Thanks.